# C # Data Annotation with Recursive class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, annotations, data-annotations, c#-8.0

We have a requirement where in we have a class consists of multiple different class. Look at the below example.

```
public class ClaimData
{
    [ValidateObject]
    public Claim Claim { get; set; }
    [ValidateObject]
    public Party Party { get; set; }
}

public class Claim
{
    [Required]
    public string ClaimNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastUpdateUserId { get; set; }
}

 public class Party
{        
    [RequiredIf("Claim.ClaimNumber", "12345678", ErrorMessage ="Address is required")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [MinLength(5)]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    [Phone]
    [Required]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Look into the annotation which we trying to apply for Address1 based on claim model ClaimNumber (which is part of another class). As far as I know we can apply condition or dependent validation with the property belongs to the same class,  Is there any way we can build dependency with other call property?

We have multiple similar requirement, where  attribute of one class is depending on attribute of another class.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pani

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is. Can't you just have a read-only boolean property `Address1Required` and put all your validation `RequiredIf` logic in there?

Comment: If it was not clear, sorry about that, I have edited the question. If we see Adress1 property is depending on ClaimNumber which is in another class. We can build dependency with any property with in same class, can we build that dependency with property with in another class is what my question?

Comment: Does this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286684/requiredif-required-for-check-validation-required-on-data-dataannotations) helpful to you?

Comment: Yinqui, Thanks for the link, That is regular RequiredIF, Not the one I am looking for.